# Identity from stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^n \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x \sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k)x^k$ where $S(n,k)$ is the number of partitions of $[n]$ into $k$ non-empty blocks (Stirling number).  I have that $\sum_{j=1}^n S(n,j)k_{(j)} = k^n$. $k_{(j)}$ is the falling factorial of k which is $k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-(j-1))$. So using this identity you get $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^n \frac{x^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n S(n,j)k_{(j)}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.  I am not sure where to go from here, my first thought was changing the order of summation but I can't seem to get anything useful out of that.

Comment: You can express $k_{(j)}$ as $\frac {k!}{(j-1)!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that

$$e^x=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

is the exponential generating function (egf) of the sequence $a_k=1$ for all $k\ge 0$. Similarly,

$$g(x)=\sum_{k\ge 1}S(n,k)x^k=\sum_{k\ge 1}k!S(n,k)\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

is the egf of the sequence $a_k=k!S(n,k)$ for $k\ge 0$. Thus, $e^xg(x)$ is the egf of the sequence

$$a_k=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}jj!S(n,j)\tag{1}$$

for $k\ge 0$, the binomial convolution of the first two sequences. The theorem is then that if $a_k$ is defined as in $(1)$, then $a_k=k^n$ for $k\ge 1$. This follows from an easy combinatorial argument. On the one hand, $k^n$ is the number of functions from $[n]$ to $[k]$. I leave it to you to verify that $a_k$ is the same thing, counted by the cardinality of the actual range of the function.